# SSIS steps to load CSV from Azure blob to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, csv, azure, ssis, azure-blob-storage

I need to connect to a CSV file in an Azure blob (source), then load the data into an Azure SQL Server table, then move the CSV file to a different (archive) Azure blob.

Without Azure, I would create a flat file connection to a local file, then a `Data Flow task` using Source Assistant & Destination Assistant to load the data into a SQL Server table, then a `File System task` in `Control Flow` to move the file to the Archive directory.

I'd like to do something similar, with a direct connection to the file in the Azure blob, then after the Data Flow task, do a file Move from one Azure blob (source) to another Azure Blob (archive).

The best I can figure is to use the `Azure Blob Download task` to move the CSV to the Azure VM where SSIS is running (by the way, can you get an Azure SSIS service without a VM?), then after download create a `flat file connection` & `Data Flow` to load the data, then  perform an `Azure Blob Upload task` to the Archive Blob.

Seems there should be a way to connect to the source Azure blob file & read from it directly without having to download it first.  Likewise, seems there should be a way to move files between Azure blob containers. Best I can come up with is the download/upload option, but that requires an intermediate location (local directory), and doesn't remove the source file after download.  Are there SSIS Azure tools to do these tasks?

Comment: Instead of blob upload/download try the blob source and blob destination, you may be able to achieve. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis

Comment: Gopi, I think the Blob Source & Blob Destination will work well for the Data Flow task (not sure how I missed them!) Any ideas for the other half of the problem: moving the files from the Source blob to an Archive blob after processing them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Any ideas for the other half of the problem: moving the files from the Source blob to an Archive blob after processing them?

As I known, there is no in-build task for you to achieve this purpose. Based on my test, I assume that you could leverage [Script Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/configuring-the-script-task-in-the-script-task-editor) and write code (VB or C#) to handle blobs directly. Here are my detailed steps, you could refer to them:

1) Use [Azure Blob Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/azure-blob-source) and [OLE DB Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-7-adding-and-configuring-the-ole-db-destination) under **Data Flow** for loading a CSV file from Azure Blob into Azure SQL database.

[image]

2) After successfully load the CSV data into SQL table, use a Script Task for moving the source blob to an archive blob.

[image]

I would invoke Blob Service REST API [copy Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/copy-blob) and [Delete Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/delete-blob) with [Container SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2), you could leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) and follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-blobs#get-the-sas-for-a-blob-container) to generate the SAS token for your blob container.

Assuming the source blob and destination blob are under the same container, then I add three variables (`SourceBlobUrl`,`ContainerSasToken`,`ArchiveBlobUrl`) as follows and add them as ReadOnlyVariables in **Script Task Editor**, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/using-variables-in-the-script-task) for using Variables in the Script Task.

[image]

Click **Edit Script** button under Script Task Editor to launch the VSTA development environment in which you write your custom script. Here is the Main method under `ScriptMain.cs` as follows:

```
public async void Main()
{
    // TODO: Add your code here
    string sasToken = Dts.Variables["ContainerSasToken"].Value.ToString();
    string sourceBlobUrl = Dts.Variables["SourceBlobUrl"].Value.ToString();
    string archiveBlobUrl = Dts.Variables["ArchiveBlobUrl"].Value.ToString();

    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-copy-source", sourceBlobUrl + sasToken);
        //copy source blob to archive blob
        Dts.Log($"start copying blob from [{sourceBlobUrl}] to [{archiveBlobUrl}]...", 0, new byte[0]);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(archiveBlobUrl + sasToken, null);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            Dts.Log($"start deleting blob [{sourceBlobUrl}]...", 0, new byte[0]);
            //delete source blob
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.DeleteAsync(sourceBlobUrl + sasToken);
            if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted || result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                return;
            }
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "Script Task - Move source blob to an archive blob", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]
[image]

Additionally, you could also leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) to access storage blob, at this point, you need to load the assembly in a SSIS script task that is not in the GAC, for more details you could refer to this official [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/).

Comment: Wow, very complete answer.  In researching this, I agree that, at this time there appears to be no way to do this other than a Script task.  My code will end up being a little different because I don't have URLs; I am using parameterized connection managers (parameters of account name & key) for the two Azure accounts (source & archive), and then using parameters for the container & blob files.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Bruce, I decided to use the Azure Storage Client Library, which is different from the solution presented by Bruce, so I am posting my working code for anyone who wants to take this approach.

I found two good references for this:

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2015/10/azure-file-system-task-for-ssis.html

http://cc.davelozinski.com/code/csharp-azure-blob-storage-manager-class

First, in the Script task, Add Reference to the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` assembly (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.9\ToolsRef)

Second, add Namespace references:

```
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

Finally, here is the full main method to move a file between Azure storage accounts:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // Get parameter values
        string blobFile = Dts.Variables["$Package::NewClientFile"].Value.ToString();
        string containerName = Dts.Variables["$Project::ClientContainer"].Value.ToString();

        // get connections
        string connStrSource = Dts.Connections["azureadhocstorage"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction).ToString();
        string connStrTarget = Dts.Connections["azurearchivestorage"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction).ToString();

        try
        {
            // Retrieve storage accounts from connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAcctSource = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connStrSource);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAcctTarget = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connStrTarget);

            // Create the blob clients
            CloudBlobClient blobClientSource = storageAcctSource.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobClient blobClientTarget = storageAcctTarget.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Create a reference to the container you want to delete
            CloudBlobContainer containerSource = blobClientSource.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            CloudBlobContainer containerTarget = blobClientTarget.GetContainerReference(containerName);

            // get blockblob (the files) references
            CloudBlockBlob blobBlockSource = containerSource.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFile);
            CloudBlockBlob blobBlockTarget = containerTarget.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFile);

            // copy the source to the target, waiting for it to finish (it is Asynchronous between separate accounts)
            blobBlockTarget.StartCopy(blobBlockSource);
            while (blobBlockTarget.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
            {
                // not done copying yet, so go to sleep
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                // refresh the copy status
                blobBlockTarget.FetchAttributes();
            }

            // delete the source
            blobBlockSource.Delete();

            // Show success in log
            bool fireAgain = true;
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Move Block Blob", containerName + ": " + blobFile + " was moved successfully", string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

            // Close Script Task with Success
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Show Failure in log
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Move Block Blob", ex.Message, string.Empty, 0);

            // Close Script Task with Failure
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
```