# Connection to Azure Blob and delete file if exists

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, ssis, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement where I need to connect to Azure container using SSIS script task c# and check for a file name (abc.csv). If file exists update a variable to 1 and delete that file.

Below is a code that I have managed to write after trying several sites:-

```
#region Namespaces
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
#endregion

      public void Main()
            {
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
       new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
       "Account_Name","XXX0sCXXQsBXXXxMnXXXXXXNXXXPCjPQ=="), true);

                // Create a blob client.
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                // Get a reference to a container named "mycontainer."
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");

                if (container.GetBlockBlobReference("abc.csv").Exists())
                {
                    Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = "1";
                }
```

The above script fails with invocation error. And I am not sure how to delete the file once variable is updated to 1.

Comment: Where does it fail?

Comment: I get error:- Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: Maybe you need to look for the innerException of your code. Use F12 to debug step by step.

Answer (score 1):

As I have tested, before `Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = "1";` it always work well.

So I suggest that you could check if your Script Task is **ReadOnlyVariables** or **ReadWriteVariables**. Here is someone load CSV from blob, you could refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130670/ssis-steps-to-load-csv-from-azure-blob-to-azure-sql/43248280#43248280).

After that, you could try to [debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/coding-and-debugging-the-script-task) the Script Task.

**Note**:
You cannot debug the Script task when you run the package in 64-bit mode.You must execute the package to debug into your Script task. If you execute only the individual task, breakpoints in the Script task code are ignored.

If you could not debug the Script Task, you could try to [implement log in your packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138020.aspx).

The Integration Services log providers can write log entries to text files, SQL Server Profiler, SQL Server, Windows Event Log, or XML files.